# How to get the count of checked rows of a table on a button click using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, dom-events

I'm working with Asp .net MVC3 following is my table,

```
  <table id="myIndiaTable">
     <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Select All<input type="checkbox" class="chkhead" onchange="Getchecked()"/></th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkdata"/></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkdata"/></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>yyytd>
     </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkdata"/></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>zzz</td>
     </tr> 
     </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="btn">
 <input type="button" name = "Submit" value ="Submit" onclick ="GetValues()"/>
 </div>
```

When I click the submit button I have to get the count of selected rows count as an alert. How can I get this using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pure javascript

thi line `ckbox = document.getElementsByClassName("chkdata");` will get all the element with class name `chkdata` return an array of element and then we loop through those element to check how many element are checked .if it is checked then we increment the counter otherwise continue to loop

```
ckbox = document.getElementsByClassName("chkdata");
count=0;
for(var i=0;i<ckbox.length;i++){
 element = ckbox[i];
  if(element.checked){
   count++;
  }
}
alert("Number : " + count);
```

Comment: Please add more details to your answer. As it is not it is low quality.

Comment: what is the jquery to check whether the first row first cell value i.e,checkbox value whether checked or not?

Answer (score 2):

USe `:checked` for getting the checked checkboxes,

```
$( ".chkdata:checked" ).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the checked checkboxes with class `chkdata` inside the table `myIndiaTable`

```
function GetValues(){
    alert($('#myIndiaTable .chkdata:checked').length)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get only the checked checkboxs in the table use

```
$('#myIndiaTable').find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length
```